# App crashing when trying to save to SD Card

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-sdcard

I'm trying to make an app that averages colour and stuff, which I have. I've got my colour in an `ImageView` and have made it into a bitmap, which I want to save on the SD card. But when I press the button to try and make it do so, it crashes.

I'm also hoping to give it its' own folder when saving, and a custom file name. (In an ideal world, I'd like one that increases by one each time, like **Swatch_01.png**, **Swatch_02.png**, etc.)

If it's something simple then I might cry a little bit.

**Edit:** Thank you guys, it's fixed. It hadn't created the JAverager_Swatches folder and the imageView wasn't converting to bitmap correctly. I had a look at it after a good amount of sleep and managed to solve it.

```
package com.colours.javerager;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AverageImageActivity extends Activity { 

public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
public TextView red;
public TextView green;
public TextView blue;
public TextView hex;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_average_image);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.hide(); //hides action bar        

    final int avgColour2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("totalvalue");
    ImageView imgtest = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.averageColourGenerated);

    imgtest.setBackgroundColor(avgColour2);

    final int r = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("redValue");
    final int g = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("greenValue");
    final int b = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("blueValue");
    final String hx = getIntent().getExtras().getString("hexValue");

    red = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.redTxt);
    red.setText("R: " + r);

    green = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.greenTxt);
    green.setText("G: " + g);

    blue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.blueTxt);
    blue.setText("B: " + b);

    hex = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hexTxt);
    hex.setText("Hex: #" + hx);

}

public void clickSaveButton(View v){

    final int avgColour2 = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("totalvalue");

    ImageView imgtest = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.averageColourGenerated);

    imgtest.setBackgroundColor(avgColour2);

    BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) imgtest.getDrawable();
    final Bitmap bmpimg = drawable.getBitmap();
        //turns imageView into a bitmap to save it

    OutputStream outStream = null;
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Javerager_Swatches/", "Swatch.PNG");
    try {
        outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bmpimg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

   } catch (IOException e) {
   }

}

public void clickHomeButton(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MenuScreenActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Edit: There's a lot of logcat stuff and it's red and angry so ;~;

> 04-19 23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184): Process:
>   com.colours.javerager, PID: 1184
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not
>   execute method of the activity
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184):   at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3814)
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184):   at
>   android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184):   at
>   android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184): Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184):   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>
> 04-19
>   23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):     at
>   android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3809)
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184):   ... 11 more
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1184): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):    at
>   com.colours.javerager.AverageImageActivity.clickSaveButton(AverageImageActivity.java:81)
>
> 04-19 23:30:54.308: E/AndroidRuntime(1184):    ... 14 more

Comment: When your app crashes, the ideal next thing you should do is to see your logcat and see what is the error is coming.What is the exception coming ?

Comment: did u given permission of write ExternalStorage in manifest & please provide Logcat Error..

Comment: There's so much red. It says something about IllegalStateException; InvocationTargetException and NullPointerException are mentioned also.

Comment: Check if the Swatch.PNG file exists in the path. It could be the file path is wrong

Comment: Please, let us see your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Also what's in **AverageImageActivity.java** line 81?

Comment: I've given permission in the Manifest to write to the external storage as it was needed in the previous activity to save an image. But this is a slightly different type of saving and the one in that activity doesn't work for this one. I think it might be the file path but I'm not sure...

Answer (score 0):

Please check two subject. such as

number 1# check permission in AndroidMenifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

number 2# check Javerager_Swatches exist directory or not in SD Card.